# rotate to mouse kinetic js

Tags: rotation, mouse, kineticjs

I looked at many examples but so far nothing worked. I want the circle to rotate on mousemove and it is rotating centered, so no problems so far. But, it does a 180 jump when I pass half of the stage. So everything is fine till I pass the half of the stage, clearly I'm missing something. `Math.atan2` gives me an error: the circle jumps to the (0,0) of the stage.

Please help I really need this badly.

Thanks in advance!

```
new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: cGrad1, 
  x: stage.getWidth()/2, 
  y: stage.getHeight()/2,
  duration: 1,
  opacity:1,
  easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut
}).play();

clickO.on('mousemove', function() {  
  for(var n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
    var shape = cGradlayer1.getChildren()[n];
    var stage = shape.getStage();
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var x =  mousePos.x - shape.getPosition().x;
    var y = mousePos.y -shape.getPosition().y ;
    var degree = (Math.PI)+(Math.atan(y/x));

    shape.setAttrs({
      rotation: degree
    })
    cGradlayer1.draw()
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still having trouble understanding what you are trying to do exactly. Could you possibly set up a jsfiddle to illustrate what's going wrong? What "should" happen when you `mousemove` over click0? Are all the shapes supposed to rotate to face where the mouse pointer is?

Comment: the clickO is just a transparent layer to get the clickposition. All shapes should rotate to the same point. I tried to setup a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/koyotee/3yTPB/6/) It would be great if you can help. There are lots of javascript and css examples that work but the I could not get in to work in kinetic js.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is what I came up with, and hopefully it's close to what you were looking for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/ttUd4/)

Basically, to calculate the angle you want to rotate to, we need to store two points:

1. The origin of the shape (centre coordinate)
2. The coordinate of the mouse click

Once you have that, you can calculate the angle between the two points with a little bit of trigonometry (Sorry if I am not accurate here, Trigonometry is not my strong suit). Calculate the distance between the two points `(dx, dy)` and then use the trig formula to find the angle in degrees.

```
layer.on('click', function() {
  var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
  var x = mousePos.x;
  var y = mousePos.y;
  var rectX = rect.getX()+rect.getWidth()/2;
  var rectY = rect.getY()+rect.getHeight()/2;
  var dx = x - rectX;
  var dy = y - rectY;
  var rotation = (Math.atan2(dy, dx)*180/Math.PI+360)%360;

  var rotateOnClick = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: rect,
    duration: 1,
    rotationDeg: rotation,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut
  });
  rotateOnClick.play();
});
```

**EDIT:**

Based off the gathered information below (which I came to the same conclusion as) I have updated my fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/ttUd4/)

As markE mentioned below in the comments, KineticJS does not support "force-clockwise flag", so the rotation always jumps when rotating past 360 in the clockwise direction, or past 0 in the counter clockwise position. Otherwise, we know  that the rotation works properly.

So, to fix this manually there are two cases we need to consider:

1. When we rotate past 360 in the clockwise direction.
2. When we rotate past 0 in the counter clockwise direction.

And this is the math I used to calculate whether to counter the rotation or not:

```
var currentDeg = rect.getRotationDeg();

var oneWay = rotation - currentDeg;
var oneWayAbsolute = Math.abs(rotation - currentDeg);
var otherWay = 360-oneWayAbsolute;

if (otherWay < oneWayAbsolute) { 
    //Take the other way
    if (oneWay > 0) {
        //Clicked direction was positive/clockwise
        var trueRotation = currentDeg - otherWay;
    } else {
        //Clicked direction was negative/counter clockwise
        var trueRotation = currentDeg + otherWay;
    }
} else {
    //Take the clicked way
    var trueRotation = rotation;
}
```

Basically we want to figure out which way to rotate, by comparing the angle degrees of which direction would be closer, the direction we clicked in, or the opposite way.

If we determined that the `otherWay` was closer to the `currentDeg`, then we need to see if the direction we clicked in was in the counter clockwise (negative) or clockwise (positive) direction, and we set the `otherWay` direction to go in the opposite direction.

And then you can normalise the `rotationDeg` `onFinish` event.

```
var rotateOnClick = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: rect,
    duration: 1,
    rotationDeg: trueRotation,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut,
    onFinish: function() {
        trueRotation = (trueRotation+360)%360;
        rect.setRotationDeg(trueRotation);
        layer.draw();
    }
});
```

Comment: this is pretty near. It also does the 180-"jump" but it is very good and close to what Im looking for. As you sad its not accurate but thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Well hopefully you could work off of it and get it to perfection! :) I didn't notice the "180 jump" but I didn't test it too much yet. When you do figure it out, come back here and post your answer and mark it as accepted, we'd love to know and see how you worked things out. If I find anything else I'll let you know here too :P

Comment: +1 @projeqht: I didn't see any "hitch" in your answer either...but just in case you could normalize the rotation angle:     var rotation = (Math.atan2(dy, dx)*180/Math.PI+360)%360;

Comment: You can see the "hitch" if you click around in a circle. At some point it rotates wrong. It rotates to the clicked point in the wrong direction. Cant believe I'm the only one seeing it. No offence.

Comment: @koyotee:  Ahhh...you want to disallow counter-clockwise--that's new information :P   Anyway, KineticJS doesn't seem to have a force-clockwise flag on it's rotation property (except on its Wedge).  There are at least 2 alternatives.  Greensock has a Kinetic tweening plugin that does have a force-clockwise flag:  http://forums.greensock.com/topic/7698-kineticjs-plugin/   Or you could also do the rotation tweening yourself using normalized Math.atan2.

Comment: Ok I will try it with the Greensock-plugin. What does the normalize mean? the code above has the same problem. Can you give an example? And thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sometimes a computed angle is outside the normal range of 0-360 degrees of a circle (let's say 420 degrees).  You can convert that angle to a proper angle inside the circle (0-360) like this:  angle = (angle+360)%360.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as you too @markE, I updated my answer above. Hopefully I did it properly.. Haha

Comment: Its near to perfect: But not always the same side is focused. When you use an arrow or a triangle you can see it but thanks for this. It is great.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the x and y position of the Tween as follows:

```
new Kinetic.Tween({
  x: mousePos.x,
  y: mousePos.y,
  node: shape, 
  rotation: degree,
  easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut,
  duration:1,
}).play();
```

See this tutorial for reference http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stop-and-resume-transitions-with-kineticjs/

Comment: Hm I think this tweens the shape to mouseposition. I want it to stay in place and rotate to the clicked position. My Problem is that the way it rotates is strange. It jumps when it passes i guess 180 degree. I tried some fomurlas but non seem to work correctly. But thanks for your answer anyway!